# Retrieving JS' Object value without knowing it's name

Tags: javascript

This is a fairly common question here in SO, and I've looked into quite a few of them before deciding to ask this question.

I have a function, hereby called `CheckObjectConsistency`  which receives a single parameter, an object of the following syntax:

```
objEntry:
{
        objCheck: anotherObject,
        properties: [
            {
                //PropertyValue: (integer,string,double,whatever), //this won't work.
                PropertyName: string,
                ifDefined: function,
                ifUndefined: function
            }
            ,...
        ]
}
```

What this function does is... considering the given parameter is correctly designed, it gets the objCheck contained within it (`var chk = objEntry.objCheck;`), It then procedes to check if it contains the `properties` contained in this collection.

Like this

```
for(x=0;x<=properties.length;x++){
    if(objCheck.hasOwnProperty(properties[x].PropertyName)){
        properties[x].ifDefined();               
    }       
    else{
        properties[x].ifUndefined();
    }
```

What I want is... I want to bring it to yet another level of dynamicity: Given the propositions that `IfDefined` and `IfUndefined` are functions to be called, respectively, if the currently-pointed PropertyName exists, and otherwise, I want to call these functions while providing them, as parameters, the very `objCheck.PropertyName`'s value, so that it can be treated before returning to the user.

I'll give a usage example:

I will feed this function an object I received from an external provider (say, a foreign JSON-returning-WebService) from which I know a few properties that may or may not be defined. 
For example, this object can be either:

```
var userData1 = {
    userID : 1
    userName: "JoffreyBaratheon",
    cargo: "King",
    age: 12,
    motherID : 2,
    //fatherID: 5,--Not defined
    Status: Alive
}
```

or

```
var userData2 = {
    userID : 
    userName: "Gendry",
    cargo: "Forger Apprentice",
    //age: 35, -- Not Defined
    //motherID: 4,-- Not Defined
    fatherID: 3,
    Status:    Alive
}
```

My function will receive:

```
var objEntry=
{
        objCheck: userData1,
        properties: [
            {
                PropertyName: "age",
                ifDefined: function(val){alert("He/she has an age defined, it's "+val+" !");},
                ifUndefined:  function(){alert("He/she does not have an age defined, so we're assuming 20.");},
            },
            {
                PropertyName: "fatherID",
                ifDefined: function(val){alert("He/she has a known father, his ID is "+val+" !");},
                ifUndefined:  function(){alert("Oh, phooey, we don't (blink!blink!) know who his father is!");},
            }

        ]
}

CheckObjectConsistency(objEntry); // Will alert twice, saying that Joffrey's age is 12, and that his father is supposedly unknown.
```

`ifDefined` will only actually work if, instead of `properties[x].ifDefined();`, I somehow provide it with `properties[x].ifDefined(PropertyValue);`. And here, at last, lies my question.

Being *inside* the consistency-checking-function, I only know a given property's name if it's provided. Being *inside* it, I can't simply call it's value, since there is no such function as  `properties[x].ifUndefined(properties[x].GetValueFromProperty(properties[x].PropertyName))` ,... is there?

I'm sorry. Not being a native english speaker (I'm brazilian), I can't properly express my doubts in a short way, so I prefer to take my time writing a long text, in an (hopefully not wasted) attempt to make it clearer.

If, even so, my doubt is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the bracket notation here. It allows you to provide an arbitrary value as key to access the object. Also, you know its name. You have your `properties` object right?

```
objEntry.properties.forEach(function(property){

  // Check if objCheck has a property with name given by PropertyName
  if(!objEntry.objCheck.hasOwnProperty(property.PropertyName)){

    // If it doesn't, call isUndefined
    property.isUndefined();
  } else {

    // If it does, call isDefined and passing it the value
    // Note the bracket notation, allowing us to provide an arbitrary key
    // provided by a variable value to access objCheck which in this case is
    // the value of PropertyName
    property.isDefined(objEntry.objCheck[property.PropertyName]);
  }
});
```

Oh yeah, `forEach` is a method of arrays which allows you to loop over them. You can still do the same with regular loops though.

Comment: Damn, D'UH! I should have known all that text would lead to a ridiculously simple question. 
In all the rush I've been through, I forgot that {name:"Adam"} is a mere key-value pair, so I can reach it by both, position (index) or name.
Funny thing is, I was about to comment your answer a few minutes ago, in it's first version. 
Now, I have to add: I had no idea forEach was a valid method for the array object in js. When I first glimpsed your code, I thought you were posting a C# code. :D


Thanks a lot!